# Error when colunm's width is fixed in p:column primefaces

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I want to define a fixed width for the column, I have this:

```
<p:column style="min-width: 10px;max-width: 10px" >
```

But when the text is most long, this not show correctly, it's truncate, for example:

My text: "This a large text, but not so long", what I get:

|"This a large text, |

what I want:

|"This a large text, |

|but not so long" |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.ui-datatable-tablewrapper tbody td {
   white-space: normal !important;
}
```

If it is treetable:

```
.ui-treetable tbody td {
   white-space: normal !important;
}
```